# Python multiple HTTP requests

Tags: python, post, python-requests

Can someone explain why no response data is outputted on the second HTTP POST (different URI)?

```
import requests

r = requests.post("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/scan", data={"apikey": "yourapikey"})
print(r, r.reason, r.content, r.text)
r = requests.post("https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2/file/report", data={"apikey": "yourapikey"})
print(r, r.reason, r.content, r.text)
```

**Output**:

```
<Response [200]> OK b'{"response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Invalid submission format, POST request contains no file field, please review the documentation"}' {"response_code": 0, "verbose_msg": "Invalid submission format, POST request contains no file field, please review the documentation"}
<Response [200]> OK b'[]' []
```

Comment: You do have a 200 OK, I feel like this is something wrong with the website instead of Python. Can you access through browser?

Comment: The docs suggest /v2/file/report requires a GET request, not a POST request? See: https://www.virustotal.com/en/documentation/private-api/#get-report

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that isn't the expected response?

Comment: @Bobby This has nothing to do with the website which is, in fact, a RESTful API.

Comment: @jmunsch I believe the documentation on that part is wrong. The initial description of the API says it is a HTTP POST API. In addition, the `cURL` and the PHP examples read POST.

Comment: @chepner I would expect to have the same response with the specified parameters. I suspect that `requests` might not be performing as desired (individual HTTP requests for different URIs).

Comment: @dfernan You aren't using the specified parameters. Their example request is largely different from your own, and it uses a GET request. Have you tried it with a GET request?

Comment: @dfernan it could be the case that the endpoint works with both GET and POST and that no `resource` has been specified, so it returns an empty response. Either include `resource` as query param on the GET request, or add `resource` as part of the POST request body/data.

Comment: My mistake, the behavior seems to be normal due to the lack of POST parameters.